# PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher with countryISO is not available below api level 21

Tags: android, android-edittext, libphonenumber

I want to achieve auto formatting for all countries phone, so for that I am using below code

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("#countryIso#")
```

So formation will work on basis of countryISO but **this parameterise PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher class is applied above api level 21**. How can I achieve same functionality in lower api level device's ?

If we are not using it then formation will be working only as per current device's locale. I tried libPhoneNumber library but didn't got solution.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

CountryID= manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();

use this code and get the country code and build the logic in this code

Answer (score -1):

This is not work in 21 or higher api. So you can try this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("US"));
        }else {
            mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
        }
```

and set inputType="phone"

Hope this will help!

Comment: that switches based on the compiler target, not the version of the OS it is running on.